# To Convert HTML doc to image in cocoa

Tags: objective-c

is it possible to convert the HTML page to image in cocoa?

Actually i have created the complete view in the HTML and now i want to convert the whole html preview to the image (any jpeg or png etc.).

I couldn't find any resource or sample on the web, which provides some sort of help on my above queries.It's highly appreciated if someone could share his wisdom on how I can achieve this.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: do you like to do this in iOS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, I'd like to thank sergio... his answer got me started but I thought I'd share some of the code that I didn't find obvious that I had to write to make it work:

Here's how to make a thumbnail for a page without ever having it displayed:

```
// Your width and height can be whatever you like, but if you want this to render
// off screen, you need an x and y bigger than the superview's width and height
UIWebView* webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(largerScreenDimension, largerScreenDimension, largerScreenDimension, largerScreenDimension)];
[self.view addSubview:webView]; // UIWebViews without an assigned superview don't load ever.
webView.delegate = self; // or whoever you have implement UIWebViewDelegate
webView.scalesToFit = YES; // This zooms the page appropriately to fill the entire thumbnail.
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Then implement this in your delegate:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(webView.bounds.size);
    [webView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *webViewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSData *thumbnailData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(webViewImage);
    [webView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Finally, to display this thumbnail you'll need something like:

```
thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:thumbnailData];
```

As a bonus thing I'll mention, I wanted multiple thumbnails to be generated at once. I found using `objc_setAssociatedObject()` and `objc_getAssociatedObject()` to be very helpful with keeping track of which webView was loading which thumbnail. Going into detail on how that worked is beyond the scope of this question, though.

Comment: Great answer. There's just one tiny thing that I can't get to work. I don't want the image to be in whatever ratio. so I tried to turn off scaleToFit and put my own width and height in initWithFrame. However, now I get an empty image. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @hishamaus: If you have further questions you should post them separately, I think. I haven't worked with Obj-C much lately so I'm not sure how to answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can draw your view in an image context, like this:

```
UIWebView* view = ...
....
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);    
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData *imagedata = UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewimage);
NSString *encodedString = [imageData base64Encoding];
```

Another option would be using Quartz PDF engine to create a PDF.

Comment: Actually i am trying to use the image as thumbnail in the QuickLook plugin so using webview isn't possible in it. Thanks in advance..

Comment: @Vinaj Jain: I put there a `UIWebView` because you said "i have created the complete view in the HTML and now i want to convert the whole html preview". So this is what you have, I guess. My code will create a `UIImage` which you can put in your plugin and it will work with whatever view you can draw on screen.

Comment: I'm looking to generate a thumbnail that's (larger dimension)^2 so that it can be used all the way up to full screen with either rotation  and look good. Can this code be used to generate that thumbnail entirely off of screen? (I'll comment back when I find out...)

Comment: The answer to my question from last night way YES.